# How can I find all of the specifications of a car?

Tags: car, old-cars

I am an automotive engineering student who is working on a project to pick a car, start with its specifications and make it in IPG carmaker. Then find flaws in the design and try to improve upon it.

I am not sure if this is the right stackexchange to ask this in but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some of those specifications are trade secrets, so no.

Comment: Google, patent application reviews, a letter to the company with fingers crossed, make friends with an engineer who works for the company, visual inspection on your own... I think after that youre out of luck.

Comment: Damn. I think I need to pick some car I can get my hands on.

Comment: Factory service manual?